# Asset not Found in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I am getting the "asset not found" error when I try to run my app. Here are my files.

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('I Am Rich'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      ),
      // You can also
      body: Center(child: Image(image: AssetImage("images/poor.png"))),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: i_am_poor
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1


environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/poor.png
```

File structure:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czWsB.png)

What I tried: I tried looking at docs and copy pasting directly from there while adapting it to my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Move your dashes back to align with the word `assets` like this:

```
flutter:
  assets:
  - images/
```

Also you don't need to specify `poor.png` in the `pubspec.yaml`, just the folder name will access all the images inside it.

Your structure is not inside lib. But for others: double check that your assets folder is not inside lib, because if it is you need to add it:

```
flutter:
  assets:
  - lib/images/
```

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also include the assets directory

try this AssetImage("assets/images/poor.png")

Comment: if you check his attached file structure, you will see that his directory 'images' is not inside a directory called 'assets'. Its not necessary to have a folder called 'assets'

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Comment: Add a folder called assets and put your images folder inside

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('I Am Rich'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
      ),
      // You can also
      body: Center(
      child: Image.Asset("images/poor.png"),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  ));
}
```

Comment: There is no difference between Image.Asset and AssetImage widgets. They're the same :)

Comment: Sometimes I notice when I use AssetImage nothing works but the image.asset does

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Comment: Can you share your repo with me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in your pubspec.yaml file.
Remove unnecessary spaces and do it again as

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/poor.png
```

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the images directory to assets by following the below. Ensure to maintain the right pattern and formatting, as unnecessary spaces could be an issue. Ensure to do a pub get after updating the `pubspec.yaml`

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

Note that we do not have to specify `poor.png` as adding the directory is enough.

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** click **Copy Relative Path** of the image.
**Step 2:** Copy that path inside the code like

> `AssetImage("<your_image_path>")` or `Image.asset("<your_image_path>")`

**Another way:** create **assets** folder outside the **lib** folder and set that path of the **assets** folder inside `pubspec.yaml`.
like this [pubspec.yaml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GvRF.png). then follow the above steps.

Comment: This didnt work. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your image (poor.png) is stored in a root folder in your project called `images` and not `assets`.

If the folder is called assets, then your `pubspec.yaml` file should have:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/poor.png
```

instead.